# XSD attributeGroup optional?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an attributeGroup defined in my XSD schema. From what I've read and tried out, there is no way I could specify the optionality of the usage of whole group (so that either all of the attributes are specified, or none), something like:

```
 <xs:attributeGroup name="NameDesc">
    <xs:attribute name="n" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="uinf" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:complexType name="g">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="tns:NameDesc" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
```

(note the **use="required"** I've added in the attributeGroup reference, which is not allowed). Am I right or is there a way to achieve this?

I've read [How to make "use" attribute (required/optional) depend on another value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511148/xsd-how-to-depend-the-use-attribute-required-optional-with-the-other-value), but I'm not sure this applies to my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know (someone please correct me if I'm wrong), it's impossible to make attributes dependent like that.

Could you consider making the attributeGroup an actual element?  That way the whole element could be present or not as a child element.

This would also be a better design if you were mapping your schema to objects.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be a better option. Thanks, I haven't though of that.

Comment: Could you simulate it by applying different types to elements of the same name,and only one of the types has the attribute group?  i.e. XML polymorphism, like <billTo xsi:type="ipo:USAddress">.  I'm not saying it would be practical :-)

Answer (score -1):

There is an other way to do this without the use of attributeGroup. You can use something like:

```
 <xs:complexType name="g">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="type"/>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
     <xs:attribute name="n" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="uinf" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where **minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"** make the attribute group of 3 element optional, and all required if one is used.

Reference: [W3 Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Simple_attribute_implication#Grammaticalization)

Comment: The page you cite is effectively a wish-list for solving this problem. It does not use valid XSD grammar. "In some pages for Co-constraint Use Cases, sample solutions in this style have been provided; they use standard XSD notation, except for allowing 'xsd:attribute' to appear within the content model as well as after it (in which case the declarations are unconditional)." - [W3 Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Grammaticalization)